# WCF on WAS - Do I need to host on IIS (HTTP) as well?

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, was

Perhaps I am thinking of this incorrectly:  From all of the documentation, hosting a WCF service in WAS (Windows 2008R2 / IIS 7.5) requires that I first add the WCF service to the (default) web site under IIS?

Is that true?
Would that require me then exposing the service endpoint to HTTP(S) as well?

I'd like the service to only be exposed to TCP if possible.

Comment: If you want to host the service in IIS, then yes you need to add it to the IIS applications (normally, but not always, under the default web site).  However, you can also self-host the service and host it in a Windows Service, and you can use TCP (and any other binding) if so desired.

Comment: @Tim: I want this to be hosted in WAS, but the only way I can see to do this is to add under default website, run appcmd, and then its exposed to TCP and HTTP?

Comment: It will only be exposed via HTTP if there is an endpoint listening for HTTP requests.  By default (if you change nothing) you will have a `basicHttpBinding` endpoint, but you can either explicitly set the serivce endpoint and specify something like `netTcpBinding`, or you can set the protocol mapping for `http` to something other than `basicHttpBinding`.